# Is available method in InputStream a good way to iterate through a file?

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

From the document, the function of the "available" method is:

> returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or
>   skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next
>   invocation of a method for this input stream.

So, how long does it take for this method to return a result. If I have a file with 10000 words, and I want to go through each word by checking like this:

```
while (steam.available() > 0) {
    steam.read(); // suppose that this read a word
}
```

So after each reading the first word, is the method going to go through the next 9999 words? And, after the second word, do it check the next 9998 words?

From the document, it say that the method "estimate the number of bytes", then how does it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states, the purpose is to tell you how many bytes you can read without the read call blocking. This is mostly useful for network connections, where data is filling the buffer and you might want to process as much of that data without the read call blocking, waiting for more data.

It's not commonly used and doesn't tell you anything about how much is GOING to be available over all.  For example, iv seen it used to test the length of a message, which is of course wrong, because only a part of the message may have been received at that point.

You are best to just read the whole stream until EOF is reached.  available() will only be of use if you want to process as much data as you can without blocking.  it says "estimate" because more data could be coming in all the time and you may have been able to read more bytes than available() returned at the exact moment you called it.

In practice, you need all the data from a stream, or you stop when you reach a certain value.  But this is a separate issue to how quickly it streams in from where ever it's coming from.  Wether it blocks or not - you will neither know nor care. :)